# Каст произвольного класса к int и double

Tags: c#

Попалась задача, в которой необходимо создать класс, который можно кастить к `int` и `double`, вот так:

```
double d = new MyClass();   
int a = (int)new MyClass();
```

После реализации операторов преобразования все касты работают, но

```
MyClass m = 3;  выдает
```

"cannot convert initializer type int to target type MyClass"
явный каст `MyClass m = (MyClass)3` тоже работает

Операторы:

```
public static implicit operator double(MyClass d)    
{    
        return d.number;    
}    
public static explicit operator MyClass(int r)    
{    
        MyClass result = new MyClass(r);    
        return result;    
}
```

Comment: Отлично! А в чем вопрос?

Comment: Реализуйте [операторы преобразования](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/using-conversion-operators)

Comment: _После реализации операторов преобразования_ - не все операторы реализовал. Покажи какие у тебя есть

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `implicit` - преобразования могут выполняться неявно (`MyClass m = 3;`)
- `explicit` - только по указанию пользователя, т.е явно (`MyClass m = (MyClass)3;`)

Поменяйте `explicit` во втором случае на `implicit`, что бы можно было **неявно** кастовать `MyClass m = 3;`:

```
public static implicit operator MyClass(int r)    
{    
        MyClass rational = new MyClass(r);    
        return rational;    
}
```

[Тестить](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BAAHlC)!